# How to plot pandas DataFrame with date (Year/Month)?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe populated with the following data :

```
      Date         val   count
0  2013-01         A        1 
1  2013-01         M        1
2  2013-02         M        2
3  2013-03         B        3
4  2013-03         M        5
5  2014-05         B        1
```

I'm new to matplotlib and couldn't figure how to plot this data using as Y axis (count), as X axis (Date) and having three separate curves, one for each value of val.

Comment: Please post dataframes as text, not images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`pivot`** and **`plot`** (`A` isn't showing up because it only has a single point and is getting hidden by the first point of `M`).  You also have to convert your `Date` column to `datetime` in order to accurately display the X-Axis:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='val', values='count').plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

If you'd like to show `NaN` values as zero instead, just use **`fillna`**:

```
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='val', values='count').fillna(0).plot(marker='o')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That works. The only thing missing is the date labels though

Answer (score 1):

Groupby your value, loop through and plot each line on the same axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, g in df.groupby("val"):
    g.plot(kind="line", x="Date", y="count", ax=ax, label=i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set date as your index, groupby the group column(s) ('A'), select which column you'd like to plot, and then use the SeriesGroupby method plot:

`df.set_index('Date').groupby('val')['count'].plot(legend=True)`

[image]